# alphabetical ordering of authors within a single citation

Tags: bibtex

I'm struggling to get an output for my `bibliography` the way I want it.

I'm currently using

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

however if a single citation has a list of author it places those names in alphabetical order. So this is an example, my code is this

```
@ARTICLE{oscillation,
author = {S. Goswami ,\textit{et al.}},
title = {"{Global Analysis of Neutrino Oscillation"}},
```

then my output is

> [8] et al. S. Goswami. "Global Analysis of Neutrino Oscillation".

not what i want which would be

> [8] S. Goswami, et al.  "Global Analysis of Neutrino Oscillation".

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Do you think you could turn your snippet into a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) It would really help anyone looking at your question :) Welcome!

Comment: not entirely sure how to. i do know that if i remove the comma separator in the authors list it solves the problem. However my guess is this is due to the fact that its no longer a list to the compiler and it thinks its a single author with the words in the given order. However i like the comma and there should be a better solution

Comment: One way to create a MWE is to *copy* your files into a separate directory, and then start stripping the *copied* files down to the stage where you have a file that shows your problem

Comment: The comma divides the first name and the family name. With `and` you mark a second or third autor: `first, family and first2,family2` are two autors named "first family, first2 family2". What exactly happens depends from the way you call your bibliography. So a MWE would be helpful.

Comment: That's very interesting. The way i call my bibliography is shown above plus (\bibliography{References}). However adding the word "and" just adds an and in the citation not a comma separator. but maybe that's a function of the style.

Comment: Are you sure that your claim "if a single citation has a list of author [the `unsrt` bibliography style] places those names in alphabetical order" is correct? Separately, I don't understand the need to specify the "et al" truncation (or any other truncation scheme) in the `author` field. I'd recommend writing `author = "Srubabati Goswami and Abhijit Bandyopadhyay and Sandhya Choubey"` and letting BibTeX and the bibliography style file do the formatting work for you.

Answer (score 14):

A bibliography entry should list each author separately, using `and` between them

```
author = {A. N. Other and D. Nobacon and F. Bloggs}
```

The `and` here is a special marker for BibTeX: the format of the names in the *output* will depend on the BibTeX style (`.bst`) file you use, but this only works correctly if BibTeX has the correct information on which name is which.

A comma is used between surname and first name if the surname is give first:

```
author = {Other, A. N. and Nobacon, D. and Bloggs, F.}
```

which is useful for more complex names (for example two-part surnames).

For very long lists of authors, BibTeX styles will automatically truncate the list as some preset point, adding `et al.` instead. However, if you know you'll never want all of a very long list many styles recognise the marker `others`

```
author = {A. N. Other and others}
```

which will then be relaced by `et al.` in the same format as would be used for the automatic trunctation.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion you are trying to "hack" the bibliography.

Your reference should be (full author list):

```
@ARTICLE{oscillation,
author = {Goswami, Srubabati and Bandyopadhyayb, Abhijit and Choubey, Sandhya},
title = {{Global Analysis of Neutrino Oscillation}},
```

The `,` character separates last and first names, `and` separates authors.

It then depends on the bibliography style you use to display the author list correctly.

`unsrt` will display the list of references without sorting, i.e. they will appear in the same order as they appear in the text.